# WordPress Header background image not responsive and center

Tags: css, background-position

I am using this [Wordpress Theme](http://demo.wphash.com/republik/about/)  for my website  and I have tried to  set center or full-width image header, but it's not working. Image is always left, I want to know how to do that correctly ,(Theme are not provided header to add image option )

This is my CSS

```
#header .header__top.bg-cat-1 {
  background: url("http://localhost/pro/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/HD.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  align-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use of  `background-position: center center`.

The `background-position` CSS property sets the initial position for each defined background image, relative to the background position layer defined by `background-origin`.

Default value of background-position is `0% 0%` thats why its starts from top-left corner by default.

```
#header .header__top.bg-cat-1 {
  background-image: url("http://localhost/pro/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/HD.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Reference Link:

- [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following css:

```
background-position: center;
```

If you want to fit the background to the current section, try this:

```
background-size: cover !important;
```

If there are inline styles, and you can't find where are they, you may use !important as you see on the previous code.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: sir, Thank for your solution